# Is there way to disable credential suggestion in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, deployment, material-ui

I am searching a solution to disable managed credential suggestion from browser in react js web page, so is there a possible way to do that?
thank you

I have tried with **autoComplete=off** attribute and make editable mode by handling onFocus event but still manage passwords suggestions is there

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use "autocomplete" for example: `<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="new-password" />`